# Visual Studio LightSwitch Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-lightswitch

Anybody know what the keyboard shortcut is to drop-down the list in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown has been clicked **first**, the usual key is **F4**, but by the time you've clicked on it, you might as well have just clicked on the arrow itself.

Comment: F4 for me is the global shortcut key for properties.  Also I don't use a mouse to get the focus in the first place I'm using the microphone.  Thanks for your suggestion :-)

Comment: It might have been Shift-F4 (it won't be Alt-F4 or Ctrl-F4 as they both close windows/applications).